# Devise, how to set auto redirection to a specific page if the user already logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If the user request the sign_up page (I set the root to be the sign_up page), how can I redirect the user to another one if the user is already logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add `after_sign_in_path` method to your application controller. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in